# Mutex among threads of same process

Tags: multithreading, mutex

I am using a mutex to prevent the same process from being executed twice, in this way:

```
CreateMutex( NULL, true, "MutexName" );
if ( GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS ) { return 1;}
```

So if mutex already exists in the system, then process exits.

Now I am wandering, is it possible to do a similar thing among threads of same process?
I would like to give a thread a mutex, and exit if another thread with the same mutex already exists in the process.

Comment: Why bother, when a flag would do?

Comment: This makes little sense.  You are not in control over how often the user starts your program.  So the mutex makes sense.  You are *completely* in control how often you start a thread.  There's nothing the user can do to start another one.

Comment: The fact is, new thread is created from another process. This process creates a new thread attaching a DLL in the process which I want to control: if DLL has already been loaded, then I must exit the DLL thread, to avoid injecting twice same process. I was thinking to do that using mutex, but other better solution are welcomed